# Minecraft bedrock edition @minecraft/server module beforechat event

Tags: javascript, events, module, chat, minecraft

**Manifest dependencies**

```json
{
    "module_name": "@minecraft/server",
    "version": "1.2.0-beta"
},
```

**Main.js**

```js
import * as server from "@minecraft/server"

// This is the old version for listening to a chat event (1.1.0-beta):
server.world.events.beforeChat.subscribe(function (eventData) {
    let Player = eventData.sender
    let Message = eventData.message
    Player.tell($`[${Player}]: ${Message}`)
}
```

"server.world.events.beforeChat.subscribe" is causing the error:
***TypeError**: cannot read property '**subscribe**' of undefined*

I want the server to listen to chat message events but I'm not sure how I do that with the new version. I've looked at the Microsoft documentation:

- [minecraft-server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/minecraft-server)
- [beforeevents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/beforeevents)
- [chatsendbeforeeventsignal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/scriptapi/minecraft/server/chatsendbeforeeventsignal)

Microsoft has not provided any usage examples and I cannot find any other resources.

Comment: Have you tried `server.world.beforeEvents.chatSend.subscribe(function(eventData) { ... });`?

Comment: Creates this error:
TypeError: cannot read property 'chatSend' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of @minecraft-server, I changed up your script to look like this:

```
import * as server from "@minecraft/server"

server.world.beforeEvents.chatSend.subscribe(function (eventData) {
    let player = eventData.sender
    let message = eventData.message

    switch (message) {
        case "hello":
            player.sendMessage("Hello!")
            break
        case "!creative":
            eventData.cancel = true
            player.runCommand("gamemode c")
            break;
    }
})
```

I just replace the function and put in a switch statement to detect if a player sends a hello in chat. Keep in mind, using the sendMessage function will always guarantee to send before the players message. To fix this just change beforeEvents to afterEvents.

In the second case I put "eventData.cancel = true" to delete the players message similar to commands.

Remember to update your @minecraft-server version to 1.3.0-beta in your manifest.json!

```
"modules": [
    {
        "type": "script",
        "language": "javascript",
        "uuid": /*INSERT A UUID HERE*/,
        "entry": "scripts/main.js",
        "version": [
            1, 0, 0
        ]
    }
],
"dependencies": [
    {
        "module_name": "@minecraft/server",
        "version": "1.3.0-beta"
    }
]
```

I've only just started learning scripting in Bedrock so if there's any issues here let me know.